# How to display all nodes in the mesh,not just on the border

Tags: graphs-and-networks, finite-element-method

How to display all nodes in the mesh,not just on the border
[image]

```
    Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
emesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
%["Wireframe"]
emesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
  "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Blue]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PointElements` are those elements that `DirichletConditions` can be applied to. As such you can not use those if you want to display all nodes and their IDs. That said, it's easy to write a function that does this.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
emesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
coords = emesh["Coordinates"];
Graphics[{{Point[coords]}, 
  MapThread[
   Text[#1, #2, {-1, 1}] &, {Range[Length[coords]], coords}]}]
```

[image]